# conditional: if is page, and all subpages

Tags: php, menus, css, conditional-tags

What I'm currently trying to achieve is displaying certain menus on certain pages using one template and conditional statements, like so:

```
if (is_page('donate')){
wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu'  =>  'donate',
            'container' => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'side-menu'
        ));
} elseif (is_page('about-us')) {
wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu'  =>  'about',
            'container' => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'side-menu'
        ));
}
```

As all these pages use the same template I needed something that allowed the relevant submenus to display on the relevant pages, which works fine. The problem I'm now having though, is that both pages `donate` and `about` (and more to follow) have subpages, is it at all possible to display the relevant menu on ALL the subpages as well? Thus if you're on the donate page, or a child of the donate page the donate menu will be displayed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to get the page parent, then check against that value instead of checking against the name.

```
$ancestors = array();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page');
$parent = (!empty($ancestors)) ? array_pop($ancestors) : $post->ID;
if (!empty($parent)) {
  switch ($parent){
    case 1 :
      // menu for parent page ID 1
    break;
    case 2 :
      // menu for parent page ID 2
    break;
  } 
}
```

And so on. Your numbers will need to match against the IDs of the parent pages.